# Lista encadeada sem cabeça em c

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Gostaria da saber como eu crio uma função para remover no início da lista sem cabeça.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NOME 50

typedef struct pessoa{
     char nome[MAX_NOME];
     int idade;
}Pessoa;

/*celula lista*/
typedef struct Lista{
    Pessoa *elemento;
    struct Lista *prox;
}celula;

typedef celula *Lista;
void inserir(celula *ptr, Pessoa *p){
    if( ptr == NULL){
             printf("Lista vazia ");
        return 0;
    }
  celula *novo;
  novo = malloc(sizeof(celula));
  novo->elemento= p;
  novo->prox = ptr->prox;
  ptr->prox = novo;

}
celula *inserir_inicio(celula **topo, Pessoa *p ){
     celula *novo;
  novo = malloc(sizeof(celula));
  novo->elemento= p;
  if(*topo == NULL){
    novo->prox = NULL;
    *topo = novo;
    return novo;
  }
  else{
  novo->prox =*topo;
  *topo=novo;
  return novo;
}
}
celula *remover_ini(celula **topo){
        if((*topo) == NULL){
            return printf("Lista vazia");
        }
        else{
            celula *lixo = *topo;
            (*topo)->prox = lixo->prox;
            free(lixo);
            return 1;
        }


}
void remover(celula *topo){
    if(topo->prox == NULL){
        celula *aux;
        aux = topo->prox;
        free(topo);

        return 0;

    }
    celula *lixo;
    lixo = topo->prox;
    topo->prox = lixo->prox;
    free(lixo);
  return 1;
}

void printar(celula *topo){
 celula *aux;
  aux = topo;
  if(aux == NULL){
    printf("vazio");
  }else{
  do{

   printf("Nome: %s | Idade: %d \n",aux->elemento->nome, aux->elemento->idade);
            printf("-------------------------- \n");
  aux= aux->prox;

  }while(aux!=NULL);
  }
}



 main(){
  Lista topo =NULL;
  Pessoa p1,p2,p3,p4,p;
  Pessoa *info_removida;





    p1.idade = 30;
    strcpy(p1.nome, "matheus");

    p2.idade = 18;
    strcpy(p2.nome, "mayara");

    p3.idade = 19;
    strcpy(p3.nome, "juca");

 int menu;

while ( menu != 0) {
        printf(
        "\n-----------------------------------------------------\n"
        "Selecione opcao que deseja, veja nosso menu:\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        "0 - Sair \n"
        "1 - Inserir no Inicio\n"
        "3 - exibir \n"
        "2 - Inserir \n"
        "4 - Remover \n"
        "5 - Remover ini\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        "0 - SAIR DO PROGRAMA.\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        );
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        switch (menu){

            case 0:
                printf("Voce fechou.");
            break;
            case 1:

                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p1);
                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p2);
                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p3);

            break;

             case 2:
                 inserir(topo, &p1);

            break;
            case 3:

                printar(topo);
            break;
            case 4:
              remover_ini(topo);
           break;
            case 5:
                remover(topo);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao inexistente.");
                break;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: bem vindo!! Tente indentar os seu código, para podermos ajuda-lo.

Comment: Eu não li todo o código pois encontrei logo um problema que poderá causar muitos problemas. Porque duas estruturas? Uma para a pessoa e outra para a lista? Minha sugestão: http://pastebin.com/AmgTufxD                 Para além disso idente o código e poste apenas pedaços necessários.

Comment: Ao postar uma pergunta seria interessante você definir bem o que você gostaria e quais erros está encontrando.

Comment: @krystalgamer Se usar uma estrutura só, o AP só terá uma lista de pessoas (i.e. não poderá ter listas de outras coisas, nem pessoas fora de listas). Essa separação é benéfica, se feita corretamente é claro (i.e. sem deixar sobrar nenhum acoplamento não intencional). P.S. Ok, eu percebo que nesse caso a lista é só de pessoas, pois o ponteiro é pra `Pessoa`, mas ainda assim separado fica mais fácil generalizar no futuro.

Comment: @Mateus Para você indentar o código, tem uma forma fácil :  se você usa o notepad++ ou outro editor cole o seu código nele , selecione tudo e de um tab (isso cria quatro  espaços em branco para linha de código) depois copie e cole na sua pergunta.

Comment: @PenaPintada ...ou simplesmente selecione todo o código e clique no botão "Amostra de código" (atalho Ctrl+K). :)

Comment: Matheus, se você usa a mesma estrutura pra representar uma lista e pra representar uma célula da mesma lista, então não tem jeito: ou você tem uma cabeça, ou terá que substituir a lista original (em toda parte do programa que faz referência pra ela) cada vez que remover o primeiro elemento. Uma "gambiarra" que você *poderia* fazer é remover o segundo elemento da lista, copiando o seu valor pro primeiro nó. Mas ainda assim teria problemas pra remover o último elemento da lista, então não recomendo...

Comment: @mgibsonbr  Obrigado cara, agora vou indentar os códigos mais rápidos por aqui!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vejo no seu código que já possui duas funções de remoção, mas ambas estão com o retorno errado. A função `remover` está retornando um inteiro, você declara o retorno da mesma como `void`. Tire os `return` da função `remover`.

E na função `remover_ini` que deveria retornar um ponteiro para uma célula você retorna um inteiro e depois coloca um `printf` no retorno. Retorne o `topo` da lista já com o elemento removido.

Outro problema no seu código é que a variável `menu` não tem nada na primeira execução e dessa forma o programa não faz nada. Inicializa `menu`, ao declará-la no topo da `main`.

Dessa maneira o código ao menos compila, executa e remove alguns elementos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NOME 50

typedef struct pessoa
{
     char nome[MAX_NOME];
     int idade;
}Pessoa;

/*celula lista*/
typedef struct Lista
{
    Pessoa *elemento;
    struct Lista *prox;
}celula;

typedef celula *Lista;
void inserir(celula *ptr, Pessoa *p)
{
    if( ptr == NULL)
    {
             printf("Lista vazia ");
        return 0;
    }
  celula *novo;
  novo = malloc(sizeof(celula));
  novo->elemento= p;
  novo->prox = ptr->prox;
  ptr->prox = novo;

}

celula *inserir_inicio(celula **topo, Pessoa *p )
{
     celula *novo;
     novo = malloc(sizeof(celula));
     novo->elemento= p;
     if(*topo == NULL)
     {
         novo->prox = NULL;
         *topo = novo;
         return novo;
     }
     else
     {
         novo->prox =*topo;
         *topo=novo;
         return novo;
     }
}

celula *remover_ini(celula *topo)
{
    celula *lixo = topo;
    if(lixo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lista vazia");
    }
    else
    {
        topo = topo->prox;
        printf("Elemento a ser excluido: %c", 10);
        printf("Nome: %s | Idade: %d \n",lixo->elemento->nome, lixo->elemento->idade);
        free(lixo);
    }
    return topo;

}

void remover(celula *topo)
{
    if(topo->prox == NULL)
    {
        celula *aux;
        aux = topo->prox;
        free(topo);
    }
    celula *lixo;
    lixo = topo->prox;
    topo->prox = lixo->prox;
    free(lixo);
}

void printar(celula *topo)
{
    celula *aux = topo;
    if(aux == NULL)
    {
         printf("vazio");
    }
    else
    {
          do
          {
                 printf("Nome: %s | Idade: %d \n",aux->elemento->nome, aux->elemento->idade);
                 printf("-------------------------- \n");
                 aux= aux->prox;

          }while(aux != NULL);
    }
}

main()
{
    Lista topo = NULL;
    Pessoa p1,p2,p3,p4,p;
    Pessoa *info_removida;
    int menu = 1;

    p1.idade = 30;
    strcpy(p1.nome, "matheus");

    p2.idade = 18;
    strcpy(p2.nome, "mayara");

    p3.idade = 19;
    strcpy(p3.nome, "juca");

    while ( menu != 0) 
    {
        printf(
        "\n-----------------------------------------------------\n"
        "Selecione opcao que deseja, veja nosso menu:\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        "0 - Sair \n"
        "1 - Inserir no Inicio\n"
        "3 - exibir \n"
        "2 - Inserir \n"
        "4 - Remover \n"
        "5 - Remover ini\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        "0 - SAIR DO PROGRAMA.\n"
        "-----------------\n"
        );
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        switch (menu)
        {

            case 0:
                printf("Voce fechou.");
            break;
            case 1:
                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p1);
                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p2);
                inserir_inicio(&topo, &p3);
            break;
            case 2:
                inserir(topo, &p1);
            break;
            case 3:
                printar(topo);
            break;
            case 4:
              topo = remover_ini(topo);
            break;
            case 5:
                remover(topo);
            break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao inexistente.");
             break;
            }
       }  
}
```

Comment: Olá mesmo assim não esta removendo no inicio

Comment: eu estava pensando com é uma lista sem cabeça  , queria criar uma cabeça e fazer ela apontar dai eu removia o primeiro elemento mais não esta dando certo

Comment: A função remover esta funcionando mas a funcão remover inicio ainda não esta retornando nada

Comment: @Matheus Francisco, está corrigido. A função `remover_ini` opção 4 do menu faz o desejado.

Comment: sim a função esta fazendo o que deseja sim agora eu estou tentando criar uma funcao    
celula *Busca(celula *topo, Pessoa *p){
    celula*aux;
    aux = topo->prox;
    while(e eu tenho q encontrar tipo o sobnome mas se matheus não tiver sobrenome ira retorna NULL entendeu ?
}  e uma que vai listar todos os elementos mas apenas os sobre nome se não tiver so vai dar o tamanho da lista .. acho que é isso !

Comment: é uma função que vai buscar se o nome tem um sobrenome .. tipo nome matheus tem algum sobrenome se tiver vai retornar o sobrenome ...  http://i58.tinypic.com/ddpag8.png

Comment: Busca(Pessoa *p, celula *topo){
    celula*aux;
    aux = topo->prox;
    while(aux != NULL && aux->elemento->nome != p)
        aux = aux->prox;
    return aux;
}  mas eu tenho que buscar se o nome tem um char subnome

Comment: Compreendi, pode criar um elemento na estrutura `pessoa` para armazenar o sobrenome ou pode verificar se existem espaços no `nome`.

Comment: Mas o SOpt é um Q&A que propõe uma estrutura de perguntas e respostas somente. E cada pergunta deve ser passível de apenas uma resposta, sendo  assim se a proposta inicial desta questão foi atendida sugiro que aceite-a como certa e abra uma segunda questão apresentando esta dificuldade e o código que já tentou criar. Assim vai obter mais sucesso!

Comment: tentei algo assim void Busca(Pessoa *p, celula *topo){
    celula*aux;
    aux = topo->prox;
    while(aux != NULL && aux->elemento->subnome == p)
        aux = aux->prox;
    return aux;
}

Comment: Assim pode funcionar `void Busca(celula *topo)
{ 
 celula *aux; 
 aux = topo; 
 while(aux != NULL)
 {
  if(aux->elemento->subnome)
   printf("%s", aux->elemento->subnome);
  aux = aux->prox;
 }
}`, mas crie outra pergunta com este assunto que você vai obter mais sucesso.